# Capturing a value of an attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have got a problem with capturing a value of attribute 'id' from button element.
How may I do it?

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    ...
    button = $('<button>').attr('type', 'button').attr('id', data[i].result_id).html('Details').click( function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function()
            {
                load('../result_details/' + ? + '/');
            }
        });
    });
    ...
}
```

---

I have thought about using AJAX to show results in dialog window, but I have no idea how to do it. I would like to avoid opening a new window in due to watching results.

Here is the code I have now:

HTML: result_browser.html

```
<form class="form" method="post" id="resultbrowserform">

    <!--Something-->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Apply </button>
</form>

<div id="dialog" title="Details">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
function serializeForm(form){...}

...

$('#resultbrowserform').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: '/browser/data/',
            data:  serializeForm($('#resultbrowserform')),
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $('#resultbrowsertablecontainer').remove();
                data = data.data;
                if (!data.length) {
                    window.alert('No data for selected time period');
                    return;
                }

                div = $('<div id="resultbrowsertablecontainer">');
                table = $('<table class="table table-striped">');
                header = $('<thead>');
                header.append($('<tr>')
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Die Id'))
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Application'))
                    .append( $('<th>').html('Result'))
                table.append(header);
                body = $('<tbody>');
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    row = $('<tr>');
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].die_id));
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].application));
                    row.append( $('<td>').html(data[i].result));

                    <!--I would like to avoid opening new window-->
                    link = $('<a>').attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', '/result_details/' + data[i].result_id + '/').html('Details');

                    row.append($('<td>').append(link));
                    body.append(row);
                }
                table.append(body);
                div.append(table);
                $('#resultbrowsercontainer').append(div);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You have left far too much detail out for anyone to properly understand what your problem is or what you are trying to do. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: `load('../result_details/' + button.attr('id') + '/');` ?

Comment: `load('../result_details/' + $(this).attr('id') + '/');`

Comment: You already have the value you want in `data[i].result_id`.  Just use that.